Can I add more insulation?
My basement framing is exposed and I am looking to add more batt insulation, then just drywall. There is no vapour barrier but I already have a vapour barrier and some insulation that faces concrete toward the cold side.


Is your basement dry? Then yes, you can because the existing insulation will increase the inside surface temperature and therefore the amount of humidity required to reach a condensing level.

The reason vapor barrier is needed is because the dew point temperature for your particular level of humidity is likely to occur somewhere inside the existing insulation, and that's where condensation will occur.
Since you have vapor barrier, and since your dew point is unlikely to ever fall inside that barrier (barring absurdly cold weather), you can safely add batts inside that barrier. Do not add a second barrier.
